# DOS header presented as a C data structure

Tags: c, windows

when i want to know pe file's dos header.i get this in wikibook(X86_Disassembly/Windows_Executable_Files):

```
 Here is the DOS header presented as a C data structure:  
    struct DOS_Header 
     {
    // short is 2 bytes, long is 4 bytes
         char signature[2] = "MZ";
         short lastsize;
         short nblocks;
         short nreloc;
         short hdrsize;
         short minalloc;
         short maxalloc;
         void *ss;
         void *sp;
         short checksum;
         void *ip;
         void *cs;
         short relocpos;
         short noverlay;
         short reserved1[4];
         short oem_id;
         short oem_info;
         short reserved2[10];
         long  e_lfanew;
     }
```

there're some variable define in void*;i search and get this conclusion:**"Size of VOID and CHAR pointer on 16 bit Platform is : 2 bytes , on 32 bit : 4 bytes and on 64 bit : 8 bytes. Size of void pointer and char pointer both are of same size in C/C++, but, platform dependent"**
also i build a win32 program test.exe use C++([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAA2v.png)) and void* is 4byte;
and figure out dos header is:char+25*short+long+4*void*=56+4*void*=72Byte;

but open it with winhex([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t04lA.png)),DOS header=64Byte.

in this github project(Sable/McCli/blob/master/CliKit/IO/PE/IMAGE_DOS_HEADER.cs) ,void* was replaced by ushort;

so how to understant void* size in dos header?is it always 2byte in 16bit,32bit and 64bit platform?

Comment: Get a new book. There is no language C/C++. And the size of pointers depends on the implementation, not only the register-width.

Comment: That's not a C structure. A C compiler would give you errors.

Comment: You might also want to research *padding* and how it relates to structures.

Comment: @Olaf: Who said there was a language called C/C++?

Comment: The document how a chunk of binary data is allocated by showing a C struct is complete nonsense. In order to understand the binary data, you need proper documentation. When you have that, you can then create a C representation of that data accordingly.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley 1) read the question. 2) This is a common phrase to make clear C and C++ are **different** languages. 3) Did I say there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C struct provided is only an example (and it should be updated at the wiki). In `winnt.h` there is a full definition. You'll see that there are no pointers in the struct but that they are "initial sizes". The definition is:

```
#pragma pack(push,2)
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {      // DOS .EXE header
    WORD   e_magic;                     // Magic number
    WORD   e_cblp;                      // Bytes on last page of file
    WORD   e_cp;                        // Pages in file
    WORD   e_crlc;                      // Relocations
    WORD   e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
    WORD   e_minalloc;                  // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_maxalloc;                  // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    WORD   e_ss;                        // Initial (relative) SS value
    WORD   e_sp;                        // Initial SP value
    WORD   e_csum;                      // Checksum
    WORD   e_ip;                        // Initial IP value
    WORD   e_cs;                        // Initial (relative) CS value
    WORD   e_lfarlc;                    // File address of relocation table
    WORD   e_ovno;                      // Overlay number
    WORD   e_res[4];                    // Reserved words
    WORD   e_oemid;                     // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    WORD   e_oeminfo;                   // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    WORD   e_res2[10];                  // Reserved words
    LONG   e_lfanew;                    // File address of new exe header
  } IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is an address of memory, and it depends (as you said) of the architecture. Each architecture is able to address a specific amount of memory, and for it, the pointers are defined of a given size.

Examples:

- My desktop computers use 64bits for both.
- My Pic16F1709 is 8bit architecture, memory address is of different length depending on the type) 12-bits for data-memory, 15-bits for program-memory, etc.

> how to understant void* size in dos header?is it always 2byte in 16bit,32bit and 64bit platform?

You cannot say. Most of the time yes, but nothing force that.

In your code, the size of the final structure will vary.

Comment: @Lundin: Thanks, I polished the answer. What I meant is it depends how you count: those special chip architecture have not a single address space, that means the linear access is some kind of hack/merge. Example is 12-bits for data-memory, 15-bits for program-memory, etc.. I do not remember the C pointer (void*) sizeof, which could well be of 16-bit. Please, feel free to edit my answer if you think the values there are not precise enough.

Comment: It makes no sense to have pointers in a header on disk. At best they can be sizes or offsets. Thus, they don't have to be the size of a memory address of the machine.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Sorry, but I do not understand your comment. what disk, what offset?

Comment: The DOS header is a part of the executable file (on disk). The information in it is to load the executable code before running it. That information (on disk) cannot contain pointers as we use them in c (e.g. a `void *sp`). So at best these "pointers" can be offsets or sizes. For example the `void *sp` in the original question is actually `WORD e_sp` and contains the initial sp value relative to the ss base. So it is not a pointer and thus need not be the size of a pointer variable.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: Got it!. What happens is usually you just read and populate from a file the first few values. The pointers are filled afterward by reconstructing data-structures.

Comment: There is no use in reconstructing the header as a struct with proper pointer values. Just read the header into the struct and use that to load the code, set up segments and memory, load the registers and then transfer control (`jmp`) to the beginning of the code. That's how the loader works.